# How to preview rendered LaTeX in Julia docstrings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

VSCode has built in functionality to render Markdown files, including any LaTeX equations that may be in them. However, there are two things VSCode cannot do which are specific to Julia documentation:

1. VSCode cannot render LaTeX in a ```math block in a .md file used for documentation via Documenter, and
2. VSCode does not have the Markdown preview functionality available for Markdown content in docstrings within .jl files.

Both of these effectively make it very annoying to actually see what someone has written in documentation that includes a lot of LaTeX equations.

I am guessing it would probably be possible to figure out a way to just render the documentation locally without too much effort. But I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to have VSCode render the LaTeX in these two scenarios, which would be much easier than having to render the documentation any time you need to see what a doctoring is saying?

I tried using Cmd+Shift+V to render, but it has the limitations I described above.

Comment: I wonder if https://quarto.org would work for you? It has s VSCode extension